# How to get parameters of factory functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, closures

Assuming I've got the code in Python 3.5

```py
def factory(param):
    def f(num):
        print(param*num)
    return f

fun = factory('a')
# how do I know, that fun was created with param='a'?
fun(3)
```

How can I inspect `param` value after `fun` was created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure variables are found in [the `__closure__` attribute of the function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-32). You can check it directly, but probably the easiest approach is to [use `inspect.getclosurevars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars) to do the heavy lifting for you:

```
import inspect

def factory(param):
    def f(num):
        print(param*num)
    return f

fun = factory('a')
print(inspect.getclosurevars(fun))
```

which outputs (exact contents of `globals` and `builtins` will differ in practice):

```
ClosureVars(nonlocals={'param': 'a'}, globals={}, builtins={'print': <built-in function print>}, unbound=set())
```

or to limit it to the stuff directly looked up in nested non-global, non-builtin scopes, access the `nonlocals` attribute, which is a `dict` mapping names to the closed upon value:

```
>>> print(inspect.getclosurevars(fun).nonlocals)
{'param': 'a'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the closure of that function via the `__closure__` attribute:

```
>>> fun.__closure__[0].cell_contents
'a'
```